# Solditiy Contract size exceeded over certain bits cannot be deployed on mainnet

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have a smart contract code written with over 700 lines of code and when I am trying to deploy it locally using hardhat, it throws an error stating that the size is over a certain number of bits which is not allowed. How do I optimise my code further without removing any functionality?

I tried altering the datatypes, storage to memory optimisation and a few other things. Also, removed a few events that were being emitted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should put this in your hardhat.config & test it to confirm your smart contract can work well.

```
 hardhat: {
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    }
```

After that, you should reduce your contract size in some ways below:
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/

You should separate your big smart contract into several small contracts which take one responsibility. Or if your smart contract includes another contract code to deploy like this:

```
import "ContractA.sol";
contract Factory {
 A public a;
 function createA() public {
   a = new A();
 }
}
```

You should implement proxy https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy instead of importing the whole contractA inside.